# Selector showing different behavior in two libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I've written two scripts using two different libraries; "lxml", "bs4" for the purpose of scraping the pizza shop names not listed in the main 30 names from yellowpage. When I run my scraper containing "lxml" which is in this case the first one, It harvests the name errorlessly. However, when I run the second one in which bs4 is used, it neither fetches any data nor throws any error. Why same selector is acting differently?

First one: (Working one)

```
import requests ; from lxml import html

response = requests.get("https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=pizza&geo_location_terms=San+Francisco%2C+CA").text
tree = html.fromstring(response)
for item in tree.cssselect("div.info a[itemprop=name].business-name"):
    print(item.text)
```

Second one: (Not working)

```
import requests ; from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=pizza&geo_location_terms=San+Francisco%2C+CA").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response,"html.parser")
for item in soup.select("div.info a[itemprop=name].business-name"):
    print(item.text)
```